# DFS Folders Odd Behavior with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, microsoft-distributed-file-system

Having an odd behavior with Namespace folders in .NET 4.

- We have a service account running on a server.  Service account has access to the folder.
- Intermittently, we'll get messages from applications that say a folder doesn't exist.
- If we use the real path rather than the namespace path, we don't get this behavior
- Happens both with PS1 Scripts and .NET Applications

Comment: can it be network connectivity issues?

Comment: By working with real path, do you mean both the .NET Applications and PS1 scripts are working? Does it always work with real path (10 out of 10)?

Comment: Always works with real path

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that an application will query a DC for the namespace path, and get the real path to the folder.

How many DC's do you have? Could one of them be missing the link to the folder in question?

Comment: I'm waiting for feedback from our ad guys on this...not ignoring it

Comment: Any news on this?